# How to use fieldset in lightning Component

Tags: components, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I want to create a custom lightning component to create new Case records and need to use fieldset to include fields in component. Need to use this only for one object. I never used fieldsets so dont have any idea on it. It would be really great if you can share some sample code or any link for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this utility class

This is the wrapper class to hold the meta info about the fields

```
public with sharing class DataTableColumns {
    @AuraEnabled
    public String label {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled       
    public String fieldName {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String type {get;set;}

    public DataTableColumns(String label, String fieldName, String type){
        this.label = label;
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
        this.type = type;            
    }
}
```

Class FieldSetHelper has a method getColumns () this will return the list of DataTableColumns wrapper containing the information about the filedset columns

```
public with sharing class FieldSetHelper {

/*
    @param String strObjectName     : required. Object name to get the required filed set
    @param String strFieldSetName   : required. FieldSet name

    @return  List<DataTableColumns> list of columns in the specified fieldSet
*/
public static List<DataTableColumns> getColumns (String strObjectName, String strFieldSetName) {
    Schema.SObjectType SObjectTypeObj = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(strObjectName);
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult DescribeSObjectResultObj = SObjectTypeObj.getDescribe();            
    Schema.FieldSet fieldSetObj = DescribeSObjectResultObj.FieldSets.getMap().get(strFieldSetName);

    List<DataTableColumns> lstDataColumns = new List<DataTableColumns>();

    for( Schema.FieldSetMember eachFieldSetMember : fieldSetObj.getFields() ){
        String dataType = 
             String.valueOf(eachFieldSetMember.getType()).toLowerCase();

             DataTableColumns datacolumns = new DataTableColumns( 
             String.valueOf(eachFieldSetMember.getLabel()) ,                                                
             String.valueOf(eachFieldSetMember.getFieldPath()),                                              
             String.valueOf(eachFieldSetMember.getType()).toLowerCase() );
             lstDataColumns.add(datacolumns);
        }
        return lstDataColumns;
    } 
}
```

After you getting all those field set information the create lightning component dynamically